# How does feeblemind affect Wisdom based casters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

[Feeblemind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/feeblemind)

> Target creature's Intelligence and Charisma scores each drop to 1. The affected creature is unable to use Intelligence- or Charisma-based skills, cast spells, understand language, or communicate coherently. Still, it knows who its friends are and can follow them and even protect them. The subject remains in this state until a heal, limited wish, miracle, or wish spell is used to cancel the effect of the feeblemind. A creature that can cast arcane spells, such as a sorcerer or a wizard, takes a -4 penalty on its saving throw.

So its clear that int and cha casters are shut down hard by the spell when they are affected. But I dont feel that its exactly clear on how wis casters (usually divine) are affected.

Take for example a cleric. Their casting ability score is not affected so they can still cast all their spell levels. The spell says that they are unable to cast spells, but it reads like an effect of the reduced int/cha, or the inability to speak clearly. So spells prepared with silent spell would help.

Are Wisdom-based casters able to still cast spells?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The affected creature is unable to [...] cast spells

So the cleric cannot cast spells, regardless of its Wisdom. Basically, *feeblemind* doesn’t **just** reduce Charisma and Intelligence, it **also** does other things, and that includes inhibiting spellcasting, all of it.

If you don’t think that’s appropriate, bring it up with your GM as a potential houserule, but it’s quite distinctly what the rules say. The fact that Wisdom-based spellcasters almost-always have Will as a strong save, and obviously are pumping Wisdom, *and* don’t take the −4 penalty to the saving throw that arcane spellcasters do, mean that they already have a large number of advantages with respect to this spell, though, so I’m not sure I would buy such an argument.

Comment: Was not an argument, simply looking for understanding as I thought the unable to cast spells might be an effect from the reduced ability scores, so if you had a way around that, such as the silent spell prepared, does a wisdom based caster get to cast the spell.

Comment: @Fering Why on earth would he? *It says the creature is unable to cast spells, so the creature is unable to cast spells.* There are absolutely no caveats or qualifications on that statement anywhere in the spell. The only way to get around it is if you found something that said “you can cast spells even under the effects of a *feeblemind* spell,” which almost-certainly doesn’t exist but under the rules that is what you would need.

Answer (score 5):

The penalty from [Feeblemind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/feeblemind) is actually more severe than the spell's description actually says.

If you look at the [Ability Scores](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Intelligence-Int-) page, the description for **1 Int** says:

> Lives by the most basic instincts, **not capable of logic or reason**

The clause about spells was added simply so people wouldn't argue about being able to cast cleric or sorcerer spells with 1 int.

The spell description only lists a few of the penalties that go along with it:

- The affected creature is unable to use Intelligence- or Charisma-based skills
- Cast spells,
- Understand language,
- Or communicate coherently

It only says Int- and Cha-based skill checks, but does not say anything about Int and Cha checks not related to skills, or extraordinary and supernatural abilities based on Int and Cha.

For instance, a magus could still enchant his blade if his level is high enough. But the penalty is actually severe enough so our magus couldnt even remember how to wield a sword.

But with the description saying **incapable of logic or reason**, the target becomes as feral as most wild animals (which have 1 or 2 Int), so i don't see how he could even remember the name of his cantrips or the name of his god if he does not understand language.

Which means that it's *not an exhaustive list*, but a few examples of the penalties.

They should fail on any check related to using their brain that is not related to **animal instincts** (which goes off by wisdom). But they are still affected by emotions and remember those they like, or those they love, or those they hate.

Note to remember, *a dog is smarter than him* (2 Int).

Comment: I dont think anything on that list stops a magus (or other characters) using a sword.

Comment: @Duncan There is (in the description of animal companion) a list of feats creature with animal-level Int can utilize. Martial Weapon Proficiency isn't one of them. He can use a sword but without actual skill (-4 for nonproficiency) - simply clubbing enemies with it no matter how, I suppose.